# Adding values from 2 different dataframes to make a new one?

Tags: r

Sorry, couldn't think of a better way to phrase the question.

Basically, how would I go about merging something similar to the following dataframes

2014:

```
Team  Goals.Scored   Goals.Conceded
MUFC      2              4
MCFC      3              0
LFC       1              6
```

2015:

```
Team  Goals.Scored   Goals.Conceded
MUFC    4                   3
MCFC    3                   2
AVFC    1                   5
```

into something like this, that would automatically add the values for matching Teams

Overall

```
Team  Goals.Scored  Goals.Conceded
MUFC      6             7
MCFC      6             2
LFC       1             6
AVFC      1             5
```

I was originally using a simple command along the lines of

```
new.df = 2014$Goals.Scored + 2015$Goals.Scored
```

but I think that only works if the teams are in the same order in both data frames, and if they're the same teams across the years? Was thinking of doing a for loop but have been unsuccessful thus far.

Would appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the two datasets are 'df1', 'df2', we place it in a `list`, rbind it with `rbindlist` from `data.table`, grouped by 'Team', we get the `sum` of the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2))[,lapply(.SD, sum) ,Team]
#   Team Goals.Scored Goals.Conceded
#1: MUFC            6              7
#2: MCFC            6              2
#3:  LFC            1              6
#4: AVFC            1              5
```

---

Or using `dplyr`, we rbind the dataset (`bind_rows`), group by 'Team', and get the `sum` of the columns using `summarise_each`.

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
           group_by(Team) %>% 
           summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

---

Or a bit more compact code will be `aggregate` from `base R` (would be slower compared to the other methods described above for big datasets).  We can use the formula with `.` suggesting all the other variables on the `lhs` of `~`.

```
aggregate(.~Team, rbind(df1, df2), sum)
#  Team Goals.Scored Goals.Conceded
#1 AVFC            1              5
#2  LFC            1              6
#3 MCFC            6              2
#4 MUFC            6              7
```

It can be otherwise written as `aggregate(cbind(Goals.Scored, Gaols.Conceded)~Team,....)`

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Had no idea about the data.table package, than you!

Comment: can you add a bit more light on what the first argument of `aggregate` means

Comment: @Saksham  Added some more info.

Comment: @akrun i have always seen examples of `aggregate` in a different way. can you point me to any article where extensive usage is done in the manner you have used it? I would be grateful.

Comment: @Saksham I don't have any link at the moment.  Hopefully, you can get something from google.